# About javascript if scroll at bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, waterfall

I have a js code to show content like Pinterest(Water Fall). Normaly, when i scroll to botttom, a short javascript will run. But when i applied code to my website
https://community.sacvn.net/post-fresh.php
the short javascript don't run. 
I think it have problem about dectect action scroll at bottom.
Can you help me ?
Thanks so much.

My js code : community.sacvn.net/build/waterfall-light.js

this is code in my html file

```
<script>

    $(function(){

        var page = 5;

        // as below
        var setting = {
            gap: 10,
            gridWidth: [0,800,1200,1600,2400],
            scrollbottom:{
                gap: 200,
                endtxt : 'No More Data !!',
                callback: function(container){
                    // if scroll to bottom, load more data...
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                             type        : 'get',
                            dataType    : 'text',
                            url         : 'build/data_fresh.php',
                            data        : {page : page},
                            success     : function (result)
                        {
                        container.append(result);
                        }}).done(function(result){
                   if(page>=0)
                    container.waterfall('sort'); 

                   else
                   container.waterfall('end'); 
                    });
                page--;                         
                }
            }
        };


        $('#box').waterfall(setting);

    });
```